using salt to upgrade Linux Mint OS
[Note: I originally posted this question on StackOverflow, but it was deleted because it was judged as off-topic. I am trying again here. For the record, there was an answer supplied, which I have copied and pasted after the question. I include the answer because I want to report its results after I have tested it. If this is inappropriate, let me know and I will delete it.]
I have been using salt for a year to manage 30 laptops. It has worked well and once everything was set up properly did not require any significant maintenance. The laptops run Linux Mint 21.1 and I want to upgrade them to 21.3. There are ways to upgrade manually by logging onto each laptop and executing a series of commands. However, doing that for each of 30 laptops would be a significant task. I was wondering if there is a way to update the OS (i.e., 21.1 -> 21.3) on each laptop using salt? If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.
I didn't try anything yet, since I have no idea what salt commands to use.

@OneCricketeer: I have transferred my question and your answer to ServerFault, since the post was deleted on StackOverflow.

It's best to remove @OneCricketeer's answer from your question and instead put it into an actual answer by clicking on the answer button. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk: Done.

[Answer supplied by: OneCricketeer].
-> Create Salt state File :
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get upgrade -y
        sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
        sudo mintupgrade check
        sudo mintupgrade download
        sudo mintupgrade upgrade -y
    - shell: /bin/bash
    - require:
      - pkg: update_apt_cache

update_apt_cache:
  pkg.uptodate:
    - refresh: True

-> save it as upgrade_mint.sls
-> Add the salt state to you master
sudo cp upgrade_mint.sls /srv/salt/
-> Target Your Minions:
Ensure that your laptops are properly targeted. You can do this by creating a top file or running the state directly.
Using a Top File:
Create or edit the top file to include your state.

 '*':
    - upgrade_mint

Directly Running the State:
Also you can directly target the minions and apply the state without using a top file:
sudo salt '*' state.apply upgrade_mint]


Sorry for the delay in reporting results. I had to buy a new server machine, which took a week to deliver and then found that I was missing some cabling, which I then bought and which took about 5 days to arrive.
Anyway, the Salt commands failed. There isn't enough space in this comment to explain the problem, but the output had this (starting at line 2978:

stderr:
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)

I would provide the whole file, but I don't see a way to attach files to a comment.

I have posted a question to the boot/install forum of Linux Mint asking if the upgrade process can be automated. You can find the post here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2493560#p2493560

@OneCricketeer: It turns out that there is python code that will do the minor versions upgrade (see: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2493588#p2493588). Is there a way to execute python code in Salt? I seem to recall that Salt code is translated into python or is it that the Salt code interpreter is written in python?

yes you can easily have Salt run Python code. Salt runs entirely in Python itself.
